# How can I fix setInterval issues when tab is inactive?

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I am learning jQuery by writing a slideshow plugin which I will release for anyone to use if it turns out well. I've got a good start, but ran into an issue. If you switch tabs, and then come back to the page it's on, the timing is all messed up. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome/7387953#7387953) which deals with the same thing, but I don't know how to apply the answer to my particular situation.

1. So, how can I fix the SetInterval tab switching bug? Seen here by switching tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/8FkYj/
2. High-fives for any suggestions on code improvements.

You can view & download the slideshow here: http://kthornbloom.com/slydeshow/ or see the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FkYj/

(Sorry for the novice js code! I at least tried to comment things well)

Comment: It's in the description, but the direct link is: http://kthornbloom.com/slydeshow/js/slydeshow.js

Comment: We don't want your project on some external server. We want a testcase in the question. This is not a personal debugging service, but a programming Q&A

Comment: Sure, here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FkYj/

Answer (score 6):

You can bind a stop event to $(window).blur, and a start event to $(window).focus so the timer stops when the tab is inactive.

Something like:

```
var interval_id;
$(window).focus(function() {
    if (!interval_id)
        interval_id = setInterval(slide, 1000);
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    interval_id = 0;
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a good start! I'll investigate this option tonight.